# How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?

Tags: support, faq, question-appropriateness, asking-questions, app-recommendation

I have a problem that I need to solve, and it may require the recommendation of an app. How do I ask this type of question so that it isn't closed?

(Inspired by [this question at meta.superuser.com](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to generally ask questions of this nature. The *Good* and the *Bad*.

### How NOT TO ASK questions that may require an app recommendation:

- "What is the best *{category}* app?"
- "List of apps that do *{some function}*"

  - or, closely related: "Is there something that does *{some function}*"
- "What is an alternative to *{some app}*?"

These questions are not useful to the general community and lead to "fluffy" link-only fodder answers. They really don't solve any problems (the main focus of any site) and it is hard to filter what is good and what isn't when there are 10+ answers all at the same rough vote count.

### How TO ASK questions that may require an app recommendation:

First of all: **Do your research**. Have you thoroughly searched for an answer? Have you searched in the [Play Store](http://play.google.com)? Do you even have a real problem you need to solve? And if so, have you attempted to solve the problem yourself? Instead of assuming a solution, **ask about your problem instead**.

If you did your research and you can describe what the problem is, then here's how to ask:

- "I have *{this problem}* that I don't know how to solve. I've already tried *{these other solutions}*. How do I do this?"
- "I have *{an app}* that doesn't work anymore. How do I troubleshoot or fix this?"
  With this type of question, make sure that you are as detailed as possible about the issue(s). If you just say "My app doesn't work!" and that's it, the question will be closed. Also, be open to other apps or solutions that may solve your issue.

Questions like these are problem-based, and lead to useful answers.

See also:

- The [Android Enthusiasts' FAQ](http://android.stackexhange.com/faq)
- [How To Ask Android Questions The Smart Way](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-to-ask-android-questions-the-smart-way)
- [FAQ: "What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here)
- [Are questions looking for apps on topic? As in: "I need an app that does XYZ?" or "I want a widget that does ABC"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353/are-questions-looking-for-apps-on-topic-as-in-i-need-an-app-that-does-xyz-o)